# Mac mini Mac OS 10.6 server migration to new hardware

Tags: mac-mini, osx-server

I have a Mac Mini with Mac OS X 10.6 Server installed. It has two external drives attached to it. One is for Time Machine and other contains data. I have bought the latest Mac Mini with Mac OS X 10.7 and two new hard drives. I want to migrate to the new hardware (the new Mac Mini and the new hard disks). Can Migration Assistant do that for me or do I have to transfer the data in the external drive manually?

Answer (score 2):

Apple prepared a nice, long document listing the steps needed to prepare for and implement a migration from an existing Snow Leopard server to Lion server.

Have a look and come back and ask more specific question if you run into any snags...

- [Lion Server: Upgrading and Migrating For Mac OS X v10.7 Lion Server](http://images.apple.com/macosx/server/docs/Upgrading_and_Migrating_v10.7.pdf)